# Ask clarification to reviewer of paper

Tags: publications, peer-review

I got a review that I cannot understand. It has a number of English grammatical and spelling errors. Also, technically it does not make any sense to me. How should I proceed? Can I somehow ask for clarification?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more as to what is your question?

Comment: Are the English language errors so severe that they are the reason the review doesn't make sense to you? Or are these just somewhat annoying and your lack of understanding is based on the content of the review?

Comment: @quarague I think he is asking clarification about stuff that have nothing to do with the article, I am thinking to answer "Thanks for raising this point, but this issue does not apply to our case", or something like that

Answer (score 2):

If English is not your own first language, then you might first want to ask someone you know with "native" English skills to help interpret the review.

Then ask the editor for clarification of the review, but be detailed about what parts of it you don't understand. Most editors will be willing to work with you, but I can't guarantee that all will. But if you don't ask you won't learn anything.

And, it may take some time to resolve this. If the editor has doubts about the reviewer or the review they may ask for another, which adds to the time.